# Apache-ssl vs mod_ssl

Tags: apache, apache2, amazon-web-services, mod-ssl

I just purchased an SSL certificate and am considering options for its implementation on my Amazon Elastic Load Balancer, which will leverage Apache2. From what I understand I have two options for implementing an SSL certificate in Apache 2 --- either apache-ssl or mod_ssl. The purpose of this question is to collect benefits/drawbacks associated with going with one or the other.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will not want apache-ssl. It is based on an ancient (prehistoric) version of Apache, uses somewhat slower libraries for the SSL stuff, and has roughly zero sized userbase. It is in overall harder to maintain if your requirements increase.